# How to eager load user Images (photoUrl)?

Tags: users, eager-loading

I've been trying to eager load user Photos, but it does not seem to work.

Here's my stripped down code:

```
{% set entries = craft.users({
    group: 'coWorkers',
    orderBy: 'lastName',
    with: [
        'getPhoto',
    ],

}) %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {% set userImage = entry.getPhoto[0] ?? null %}
    {% if userImage|length %}
        <figure class="portrait">
            <a href="{{ userURL }}"><img class="portrait_image" src="{{ entry.getPhoto.getUrl('user') }}" alt="{{ entry.fullName }}" /></a>
        </figure>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

No photos are displayed.

Preferrably I would eager load with the transform as well:

```
{% set entries = craft.users({
    group: 'mitarbeiter',
    orderBy: 'lastName',
    with: [
        ['getPhoto', { withTransforms: ['user'] }],
    ],

}) %}
```

In Craft 2 I could eager load the following way:

```
{% set entries = craft.users({
    group: 'mitarbeiter',
    orderBy: 'lastName',
    with: [
        'getPhotoUrl(320)',
    ],

}) %}
```

Anyone has done this before?

Cheers
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Your source is set to :

```
{{ entry.getPhoto.getUrl('user') }}
```

When in order to access an image, you need to give the array index (as you have in your set statement):

```
{{ entry.getPhoto[0].getUrl('user')
```

or better yet, as you have already set it to a variable

```
{{ userImage.getUrl('user') }}
```

In full, while adding in to appropriate code for eager loading your transforms:

```
{% set entries = craft.users({
    group: 'coWorkers',
    orderBy: 'lastName',
    with: [
       [
           'getPhoto', 
           { withTransforms: ['user'] }
       ],
    ]
}) %}

{% for entry in entries %}

    {% set userImage = entry.getPhoto[0] ?? null %}

    {% if userImage %}

        <figure class="portrait">
            <a href="{{ userURL }}">
                <img class="portrait_image"
                     src="{{ userImage.getUrl('user') }}"
                     alt="{{ entry.fullName }}" />
            </a>
        </figure>

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

If you need any further information, the [Official Documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html) does a excellent job of explaining how to implement this on the front end for craft 3

Comment: Hi, Meanwhile we are on craft 4 and the syntax for getting user fotos is: `{{ user.photo.url('transformHandle') }}` and my eager load syntax is this `['photo', { withTransforms: ['transformHandle'] }]`. When I try  `{{ user.photo[0].url('transformHandle') }}` it throughs an error. Do you know how to handle this on craft 4? Because it ain't eager loading the fotos...